# Showing the Posterior of Distribution of Normal Data with Uniform Prior on mu and log sigma has a t-distribution with (n-1) df

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

we were told in class that if you have data x_1, x_2, ..., x_n that are iid normal with mean = mu and variance = sigma^2 and then put a uniform prior on mu (from -M1, to M2) and log sigma (from -M2 to M2) that the resulting posterior distribution for mu follows a t-distribution with (n-1) degrees of freedom (assuming that M1 and M2 are large). Can someone help show this–I'm a bit lost. Much Thanks !!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Bayesian_inference

Comment: "that the resulting posterior distribution for mu follows a t-distribution with (n-1) degrees of freedom" -- it doesn't, because of the truncation of the posterior induced by the uniform prior. For example, all moments of the posterior will be finite, but this is not true for the $t$-distribution.

Comment: @Glen "... assuming ... large" suggests this is intended to be a limiting statement (to cope with improper priors).

Comment: It was a change to include an explicit limiting statement I was looking for.